# Complexity of index sets in nonprincipal ultrafilters

Tags: model-theory, computability, filters

Let $U$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$. It can be shown that the set $I = \{e \mid W_e \in U\}$ (where $W_e$ is the $e$th r.e. set in some given enumeration) cannot be $\Delta_2^0$ (in fact, it's at least $\Pi_2^0$-hard). Now I wish to show that there is a nonprincipal ultrafilter $U$ such that $I$ is $\Delta_3^0$.

I'm not sure how such a construction should go. I tried constructing such an ultrafilter by creating a chain of sets that at each stage would guarantee the union is an ultrafilter with the desired properties, but nothing I did quite worked out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to first build a suitable ultrafilter in the Boolean algebra generated by the r.e. sets and then extend it to the Boolean algebra of all subsets of $\omega$.  Only the first part of this is relevant to your question; the second part is automatic since, quite generally, one can extend, to any given Boolean algebra, any ultrafilter in any Boolean subalgebra.  So here goes the first part.

I'll build a decreasing $\omega$-sequence of infinite r.e. sets, $A_0\supseteq A_1\supseteq\dots$.  The intention is that, at stage $n$, the ultrafilter under construction is known to contain $A_n$ and all sets that include it modulo finite.  I start with $A_0=\omega$.  In the step from $A_n$ to $A_{n+1}$, I want to decide whether the $n$-th r.e. set $W_n$ is in my ultarafilter or not.  If $W_n$ is almost disjoint from $A_n$, then the decision has already been made, negatively, so I don't need to do anything; more precisely , I define $A_{n+1}$ to be $A_n$.  If, on the other hand, $W_n\cap A_n$ is infinite, then I put $W_n$ into my ultrafilter by setting $A_{n+1}=W_n\cap A_n$.

That completes the construction of the ultrafilter in the Boolean algebra generated by the r.e. sets.  (Note that, by making decisions about all r.e. sets, I have automatically also made decisions about all their Boolean combinations.)  Now what is the complexity of my construction?

At each step, I must decide whether a certain r.e. set $W_n\cap A_n$ is infinite.  That is a $\Pi^0_2$ question: "For every $k$, there exists a computation witnessing that some integer $>k$ is in $W_n\cap A_n$."  So an oracle for $0''$ suffices to answer this question and thus to carry out my whole computation.

Therefore, the set of $n$ such that $W_n$ is in my ultrafilter, which is also the set of $n$ such that the decision in going from $A_n$ to $A_{n+1}$ was affirmative, is recursive in $0''$.  That is, it is $\Delta^0_3$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This all seems correct to me, but could you explain how this procedure guarantees that every cofinite subset of $\omega$ ends up in the ultrafilter? Is the idea just that, once you have decided which of these r.e. sets to include, you close under the Boolean combinations which ensures the cofinite sets are included?

Comment: The key is the second sentence in the second paragraph of the answer, which includes the clause "and all sets that include it modulo finite." So the cofinite sets are in the ultrafilter as soon as I set $A_0=\omega$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks!